# How do I displace iframe / video to another div if iframe exist in the content?

Tags: php, html

Wordpress site.

I want jquery or php, or any easy solution that will grab div from div id=content (if it exist), and put it inside id=iframer div, while deleting it in id=content, on load.

```
<div id="iframer">
**/ I am waitting to get "<div class="video">All content </div>" inside me. /**
</div>

<div id="content">
<div class="video">
<iframe width="697" height="392" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xxxxxxx?feature=oembed" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
</div>
</div>
```

Result after some script...

```
<div id="iframer">
<div class="video">
<iframe width="697" height="392" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xxxxxxx?feature=oembed" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
</div>
</div>

<div id="content">
**/ Iframer stolen my content. /**
</div>
```

Comment: why dont you just add it wright away than calling it?

Comment: Probably because this HTML is generated by Wordpress or something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you can't edit the HTML directly or the code that generate this HTML but here's my solution with javascript/jQuery.

```
<script>
//A page can't be manipulated safely until the document is "ready."
$( document ).ready(function() {
  //Get the html content inside div with id='content'
  var myHtml = $( '#content' ).html();

  //Copy the HTML in the div with id='iframer'
  $( '#iframer' ).html( myHtml );

  //Delete the HTML content inside div with id='content'
  $( '#content' ).html( '' );
});
</script>
```

Comment: While it works great, page load shows that video jumps from div to div. Any solution to camuflage this?

Comment: Yes, you can use CSS to hide by default the content of div with id='content'. But you will still see the video popup in the new div (not from one to the other). The best solution would be to have the control of directly on the base source but yeah, it can be hard to change how Wordpress works.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `.detach` and `.appendTo`.  That way it preserves your event listeners, plugins etc that are bound to the DOM element.

> The `.detach()` method is the same as `.remove()`, except that `.detach()` keeps all **jQuery** data associated with the removed elements. This method is useful when removed elements are to be reinserted into the DOM at a later time

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
     $('button').click(function(){

          var content = $( '#content > .video' ).detach();

          content.appendTo('#iframer');
      });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="iframer" style="padding:5px; background:#CCC;"></div>

<button>Click</button>

<div id="content">
  <div class="video">
     Video Content here
  </div>
</div>
```

I added some background color and what-not to make it a bit more visual.

Cheers!